# ClangFormat Extension is not installed correctly on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, llvm, clang-format

We wanted to install the Visual Studio extension for LLVM/clang-format in Visual Studio 2015. On my computer the installation works. The extension shows up in the options dialog tools/options/LLVM/Clang.

On the computers of my colleagues this does not work at all. We tried to install the extension from Marketplace and also the most recent version from http://llvm.org/builds/.

Does anybody experience the same issue? Is there a known solution to this?

Update: 
Issue occurs on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Answer (score 6):

It seems that a repair installation helps. So the approach is:

1. Install the extension from Market Place
2. Repair "Microsoft Visual Studio installation with the installer.

Then it works.

Comment: How did you repair your installation?

Comment: On Windows 10 you find this option in "Apps & features" (Windows setting). Just call from there the "Microsoft Visual Studio" installer (modify button) and choose repair. Takes one hour and then it should work. Alternatively you call the installer manually.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It has to be done in that order it would seem. I first tried to uninstall the plugin then repair VS install and then install clang format again but that didn't work. Installing latest clang format then repairing VS worked.